# RxJS concatMap subscription is called for second Observable separately

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I am writing an Angular 6 app. I expect it to show a loading animation when route changes as well as there is also any pending http requests. So I have 2 Observables look like this. For httpPendingRequests, I am implementing with a counter written in Angular's HttpInterceptor; and for locationChanged, I have subscribed to Router's NavigationStart/NavigationEnd events.

```
httpPendingRequests: BehaviorSubject<number>;
locationChanged: BehaviorSubject<boolean>;
```

And I am using concatMap to subscribe to these 2 Observables, code looks like this:

```
this.locationChanged.pipe(
  concatMap(changed => {
    console.log('location change:' + changed);
    if (changed) {
      return this.httpPendingRequests;
    } else {
      return of(0);
    }
  }),      
  map(count => count > 0)
).subscribe(val => { 
  console.log('isloading: ' + val);
});
```

So I expect this to log 'isloading' to console only when location has been changed, plus if there is any pending requests. It does work in this scenario. However I found it also logs 'isloading' message when there is only pending http requests but location does not change. It made me confused, I thought the operator is making sure the Observables are subscribed in order? If the first one(location change) does not emit, then the second one(pending request) should not be triggered? Am I understanding this concept wrong?

Besides.. I have also tried other methods to combine Observables, zip, forkJoin, combineLatest - they all only triggered the subscription once in my case so I am also not very sure what was wrong.

I am glad to provide more informations if needed. Thanks in advance

Comment: is it that the `'isloading: '` logs for one time every time the component loads, even without locationChange?

Answer (score 0):

Can be solve by using `combineLatest` observable and `map` operator. Here is the demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-rxjs-concat.

Code is in `app.component.ts`. Take a look into `console.log` value to understand more.

Comment: It looks like the same issue still exists when I try this solution.

Comment: you can see it didn't happen in the demo I wrote... Probably you need to check your logic...

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at the fact that you are using `BehaviorSubject`.

`BehaviorSubject` requires always a value to emit at creation time. This means that `locationChanged` always emits at least one notification.

If you rather use `Subject` you can control when the first notification is emitted.

In the following example, taken directly from you code, you do not see anything logged since `locationChanged` never emits.

```
const httpPendingRequests = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
const locationChanged = new Subject<boolean>();

locationChanged.pipe(
    concatMap(changed => {
      console.log('location change:' + changed);
      if (changed) {
        return httpPendingRequests;
      } else {
        return of(0);
      }
    }),      
    map(count => count > 0)
  ).subscribe(val => { 
    console.log('isloading: ' + val);
});

setTimeout(() => {
    httpPendingRequests.next(1);
}, 100);
setTimeout(() => {
    httpPendingRequests.next(2);
}, 200);
setTimeout(() => {
    httpPendingRequests.next(3);
}, 300);
```